# Joomla 4: how to add tags in the template of mod_tags_similar?

Tags: joomla-4.x, tags

How to add tags in the template of mod_tags_similar? I add custom fields and other data by this code

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->quoteName(array('core_content_id', 'core_content_item_id', 'core_images', 'core_title', 'core_alias', 'core_created_time', 'core_catid')))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__ucm_content'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('core_content_id') . ' IN (' . implode(',', array_column($list, 'core_content_id')) . ')');

$extraData = $db->setQuery($query)->loadObjectList('core_content_id');
$ItemDataArray = json_decode(json_encode($extraData), true);

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/models', 'FieldsModel');
$field = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Field', 'FieldsModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

<?php foreach ($ItemDataArray as $ItemData) : ?>
<?php
   echo $field->getFieldValue(29, $ItemData['core_content_item_id']),true;
?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Maybe there is a way to add tags in this way?

Comment: Some relevant guidance on querying the database with a dynamic WHERE IN(): [How to Use IN Clause in Joomla Query](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/22898/12352).  Also, instead of calling `json_decode(json_encode($objectArray), true)` to form an array of arrays, just use Joomla's `loadAssocList()` https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#loadAssocList.28.29 oh... and that trailing `,true` on that last `echo` looks out of place.  I won't be posting an answer, because I don't know how to resolve your question.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But it would be better to tell me how to solve my problem. Do you know how?